# jQuery Bookmarklet Works Sporadically for Unknown Reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

I created a bookmarklet that uses jQuery to count the number of occurrence of certain `<div>` and `<script>` tags in the HTML and use an alert() to show the counts.  It works most of the time, but sometimes exhibits two different unexpected behaviors: 1) nothing will happen when you click the bookmarklet, or 2) clicking the bookmarklet will cause the page to reload with only the text: "[object HTMLScriptElement]" on a blank page.  The script should work regardless of whether the specific `<div>` and `<script>` tags being searched for are present on this page.  For example, the bookmarklet works on stackoverflow, even though it does not contain the specific tags. Yet it doesn't work on some sites (that also do not have the specific tags) like google.com.

Here is a page that has the spcific `<script>` tag, but the bookmarklet doesn't do anything when it is clicked: [www.laboutique.bouyguestelecom.fr](http://www.laboutique.bouyguestelecom.fr)

Here is the entirety of the bookmarklet code:

```
javascript:
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    var jQ = document.createElement('script');
    jQ.type = 'text/javascript';
    jQ.onload=runthis;
    jQ.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js';
    document.body.appendChild(jQ);
} else {
    runthis();
}

function runthis() {
    alert("total div tags: " + $('div[id^="inqC2C"]').length + "\ntotal script tags: " + $('script[src*="inq.com"]').length);
}
```

Can anyone offer any insights?

Comment: Edward solved half the problem.  His added test() function solved the problem of determining whether jQuery has loaded before running the remainder of the script.  Yet the other problem still persists: the bookmarklet still doesn't do anything on some sites, like the link I listed above: www.laboutique.bouyguestelecom.fr Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test for jQuery / $. The reason it is failing sporadically is that jQuery is being loaded but before it is evaluated, you are firing your jQuery specific calls. You need to test for jQuery as such:

```
javascript:
    function loader() {
    var jQ = document.createElement('script');
    jQ.type = 'text/javascript';
    jQ.onload=runthis;
    jQ.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js';
    document.body.appendChild(jQ);
};

function runthis() {
    if (if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        setTimeout(function() {
            loader();
        }, 300);
    } else {
        alert("total div tags: " + $('div[id^="inqC2C"]').length + "\ntotal script tags: " + $('script[src*="inq.com"]').length);
    }
};

function test() {
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        loader();
    } else {
        runthis();
    }
};

test();
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. This partially worked: adding the test() function to determine whether jQuery has loaded.  Your revised script doesn't work with the timer, however.  So the test() function solves the problem of the page getting reloaded with a blank page. Yet the other problem still persists: the bookmarklet still doesn't do anything on some sites, like the link I listed above: www.laboutique.bouyguestelecom.fr  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Sites like *www.laboutique.bouyguestelecom.fr* where your bookmarklet is not working have disabled the `$` alias (by using `jQuery.noConflict()`)

Don't use the `$` sign but `jQuery` all the time:

```
alert("total div tags: " + jQuery('div[id^="inqC2C"]').length 
    + "\ntotal script tags: " + jQuery('script[src*="inq.com"]').length);
```